# I am getting multiple error when I added write json file and convert it into dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, testing, elixir-jason

/C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/velocity_x-4.1.0/lib/src/flutter/flex.dart:51:8: Error: A constant constructor can't call a non-constant super constructor.
}) : super(
^
/C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/velocity_x-4.1.0/lib/src/flutter/flex.dart:73:8: Error: A constant constructor can't call a non-constant super constructor.
}) : super(
^
/C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/velocity_x-4.1.0/lib/src/extensions/context_ext.dart:120:27: Error: The getter 'View' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/E:/Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'View'.
  FlutterView get view => View.of(this);
  ^^^^
  /C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/velocity_x-4.1.0/lib/src/extensions/context_ext.dart:123:33: Error: The getter 'View' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/E:/Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'View'.
  FlutterView? get maybeView => View.maybeOf(this);
  ^^^^
  /C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/velocity_x-4.1.0/lib/src/extensions/misc_ext.dart:20:46: Error: The getter 'implicitView' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformDispatcher'.
- 'PlatformDispatcher' is from 'dart:ui'.
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'implicitView'.
  .instance.platformDispatcher.implicitView!.devicePixelRatio);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/velocity_x-4.1.0/lib/src/flutter/universal.dart:564:62: Error: A value of type 'EdgeInsetsGeometry?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'EdgeInsetsGeometry' because 'EdgeInsetsGeometry?' is nullable and 'EdgeInsetsGeometry' isn't.
- 'EdgeInsetsGeometry' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/edge_insets.dart' ('/E:/Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart').
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry decorationPadding = decoration!.padding;
  ^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\Dev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'E:\Dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is the error I don't know how to solve it I have checked every single code and every possible way that are in my knowledge but can't solve the error.
Even I have undo the the json code work still get these error
Can anyone can help me